# What is the default MaxPoolSize?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting the dreaded error:

> ```
> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from 
> the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use 
> and max pool size was reached.
> ```

In sql I see that I only have 116 connections open by running:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
;
```

116 seems low, and I am currently not setting the MaxPoolSize. What is the default MaxPoolSize?

I have also made sure all my connections are closed when finished.

Comment: from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx):  maximum pool size specified (100 is the default). That what you have is a Timeout error. It only suggested that it might have been caused by max pool size being reached, but it could have happened for many other reasons.

Comment: @GabrielRainha Make it an answer?

Comment: There you go. Now try and show us what are you trying to run against that server so we can have a clue on what is going on,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx): maximum pool size specified (100 is the default).

That what you have is a Timeout error. It only suggested that it might have been caused by max pool size being reached, but it could have happened for many other reasons.

Answer (score 9):

You can try adding to your connection string the following sentence `Max Pool Size=200` to see if that helps.

Another thing that can cause the problem is a connection leak.  Maybe in some cases or under some circunstances you are not closing the connection and that is causing the problem.

Here there is an example of a connection string I am using.

`Application Name=xxxx;Data Source=10.10.10.10;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=sa;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Max Pool Size=200;Connection Lifetime=600;Asynchronous Processing=true;"`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server allows a maximum of 32767 connections by default. It can be altered using sp_configure. To view your current configuration for this setting, use the following query:

```
select * from sys.configurations
where name ='user connections'
```

Comment: Sql Server allows 32767, but from the comment by @GabrielRainha says the default for the connection string is 100. I don't think this answers what the MaxPoolSize is.

Comment: although this doesnt answer the question, the sql server comment is important because if you are running 50 boxes  in your web tier (as an example) you need to make sure you dont set each box to a number that will exceed the total number available in sql server when combined together.